# In ElasticSearch, how do I get only one from list in subproperties (nested/child/whatever) and sort by it

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a type Product, which has multiple Prices, but the returned model can only ever have one price.

I need to have multiple prices in elastic, to be able to vary on time without having to reindex. I also need to be able to sort products based on price.

I have tried both with nested and child properties, but I don't seem to be able to query it correctly.

So is it possible to achieve this using elastic? If not, how should I structure my index instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up doing is to get the current price via inner hits https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html

And then add the inner hit to the model after it was returned from elastic.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the field data type to array. Then sort by for example the max value using the mode option.

See for examples:
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html